# Laravel custom Batch model for job_batches returns null on hasOne

Tags: php, laravel, batch-processing

I need to create a `hasOne` relationship between my `CsvExport` model and a batch. I've created a `Batch` model which looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Bus\BatchRepository;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Batch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'job_batches';

    /**
     * Get the batch
     */
    public function toBatch()
    {
        return resolve(BatchRepository::class)->toBatch($this);
    }
}
```

And then created a relationship on my `CsvExport model:

```php
/**
 * Get the batch linked to this CSV export schedule
 */
public function batch(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Batch::class, 'id', 'batch_id');
}
```

When I query a `CsvExport`, the **batch** key is added and is null despite the UUID of the batch being present in the `batch_id` column of my exports table. If I manually do something like `CsvExport::find(1)->batch` this will work, but I need `CsvExport::with('batch')->find(1)` which returns null.

What am I missing?

Here are my tables:

CsvExport:

[image]

Job batches (Laravel):

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the structure of your tables?

Comment: I'll update my description with screenshots. However, the `job_batches` table is obviously Laravel's

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have defined an incorrect relationship based on the structure of your table. You should define a relationship `belongsTo` in your `CsvExport` model like so:

```php
public function batch(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Batch::class);
}
```

This assumes that your `CsvExport` model has a foreign key column named `batch_id` that references the primary key column of the `Batch` model.

Then, when you want to retrieve a `CsvExport` with its associated Batch, you can use the `with()` method:

```php
$csvExport = CsvExport::with('batch')->find(1);
```

Basically it would be the same as the relationship `user` in your `CsvExport` model if it exists, since the foreign key exists in the `CsvExport` model, not in `Batch` model.